# Persistence question on using connecting table fields as predicate criteria

Tags: java, persistence

I am trying to fetch data from table `A8SPT282` that has a connector to table `A8SPT214` by a number of fields in our entity:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns(value = {@JoinColumn(name = "ORIGINATOR", referencedColumnName ="ORIGINATOR",insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "HUD_OFFICE", referencedColumnName = "HUD_OFFICE", insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "FISCAL_YEAR", referencedColumnName ="FISCAL_YEAR", insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "TRANSMITTAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "TRANSMITTAL_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
@JoinColumn(name = "NAID", referencedColumnName = "NAID",insertable = false, updatable = false) })

private A8SPT214 a8spt214 ;
```

When I do a fetch of table 282 using persistence where the builder criteria is based on fields from table 214 but I am getting an error on using the a8spt214.hudOffice field:

```
  CriteriaBuilder builder = samsSessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<A8SPT282> criteria = builder.createQuery(A8SPT282.class);
    Root<A8SPT282> root = criteria.from(A8SPT282.class);
    criteria.select(root);
    if (disbursementSequence != null) {
        Predicate pred1 = builder.and(
                builder.equal(root.get("a8spt214.hudOffice"), hudOffice),
                builder.equal(root.get("a8spt214.naid"), naid),
                builder.equal(root.get("a8spt214.disbursementSequence"), disbursementSequence));
        criteria.where(pred1);
    }
```

Are we allowed to use fields from connecting tables as part of the predicate builder in persistence?

Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please investigate  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [a8spt214.hudOffice] on this ManagedType [gov.hud.sams.entities.A8SPT282]